# Return false not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

if you have a look at http://www.zimmi.cz/edpp and you click a marker, an infowindow with a link pops up. If you click the link, new window should open. It works well in Firefox and IE (7), but in Opera both the new window and the original window loads new content. How do I tell Opera to open just a new window and let the original one remain the same?
The function on onclick of the link in the infowindow returns false, but Opera (11.64) seems to be ignoring it.
Thanks for any help.

The code looks like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(ev) {
                        //var content = bod.nazev;
                        var content = "<a href='http://www.edpp.cz/zarizeni/velke-mezirici-oslava-' onclick='return !popUpWin(this, null, 1024, 742, true);'>Aktuální stav hladiny</a>";
                        infowindow.setContent(content);

                        infowindow.setMap(null);
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        getCoords(ev.latLng);
                    });
```

PopupWin opens the new window and returns false at the same time to prevent browser from loading the link. I don't think te problem is in this function, I suppose I just don't get the scope right for returning false :-/

Comment: can you at least post a code snippet of the event handler and function in question?  Most likely you need to return from within the event handler as well.

Comment: @Wex It's 83%? Was it much lower before?

Comment: @Jleagle it was way lower (17).

Comment: What does the popupWin function look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check the window.open and other popups properties compatability

check this link [read this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html#t00)

if you want full comatability with all browsers you **should read more not just programming**

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the default behavior for an event, you should prevent the default by calling `ev.preventDefault();` in your event handler, like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //var content = bod.nazev;
    var content = "<a href='http://www.edpp.cz/zarizeni/velke-mezirici-oslava-' onclick='return !popUpWin(this, null, 1024, 742, true);'>Aktuální stav hladiny</a>";
    infowindow.setContent(content);

    infowindow.setMap(null);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    getCoords(ev.latLng);
});
```

More [information about `preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) on MDN

Comment: This event handler prevents infowindow from showing up. The thing is I don't know how to apply this to the link inside the infowindow.